# Cannot connect to SharePoint Online list from Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to connect to a SharePoint Online list from Excel, and I keep getting the error "We couldn't authenticate with the credential provided".

I logged on to this list from Excel in the past without problem, in fact this list was created by exporting an Excel spreadsheet

I have no problems connecting to the same list from Power BI for desktop, PowerApps, or Access with the same account …

Any idea on how to deal with this would be very much appreciated.  Thanks

[image]

Comment: are you working from home instead of in the office?  I've been prompted again for  username and password when trying to open documents from Sharepoint outside of the office.  Another possibility is that the Sharepoint settings have changed - are you the Sharepoint Administrator, if not contact Admin and ask them whether settings have changed.

Comment: logging into SPO is buggy AF, try ask MS for help

Comment: @Tally Thanks for your pointer, yeah I am working from home, but am the SharePoint administrator, and I can connect to the list using Access, PowerApps, and Power BI for the desktop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Power Query into a SharePoint list.

In the Excel sheet, select a cell in the Power Query result table. In the Data ribbon, click the "Get Data" dropdown at the very left of the ribbon and select **Data Source Settings**.

[image]

In the next dialog, select the SharePoint data source and click "Clear permissions".

[image]

Then refresh the query and you will be asked to enter your credentials again. Make sure to select "Microsoft account" and enter your Office 365 credentials.

[image]

**Edit after comments**

What type of query are you using? Your screenshot says "Access Web Content". That may be the problem. You need a query directly to a SharePoint list, so you need to start it with **Data ribbon > Get Data > From Online Services > From SharePoint Online List**. The follow the authentication as in the screenshots above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks yeah I did try that, but didn't work ...

Comment: "did not work" is never good enough. It looks like you are using the wrong connector. I added some more info in my post about a SharePoint Online list connection. Try that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the https verb back to http it worked. Could you try to connect to the SharePoint site with `http://domain.com`  and see if it helps?